# Python Type Hinting: type hint a function with *args

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's say we want to type hint a function that takes in a positional argument and an arbitrary number of more arguments, e.g.

```
def foo(a: int, *args: Any) -> None:
    for arg in args:
        print(a, isinstance(arg, int))
```

and we have another function that takes in `foo`, so we want to know how to type hint `foo` as itself. Is it correct to write it as `Callable[[int, Any], None]`? I'm confused because the types in the inner square bracket (i.e. `[int, Any]`) must be as many as the arguments of `foo` -- must they be so? -- but, apparently `*args` can be any number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Python 3.10, the best you can do is type `foo` as `Callable[..., None]`, indicating it takes an arbitrary number of arbitrary arguments. You can't specify that at least one `int` argument must be passed as the first.

In Python 3.10, you can use `typing.Concatenate` and `typing.ParamSpec` to more closely match the type.

```
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec('P')
def bar(f: Callable[Concatenate[int, P], None]):
    ...
```

Comment: But please remember: One reason why Python became so popular is because that it does not have static typing and you save much time not detailing out all the types. Type hints are pureley optional. If they make everything more complicated then you shouldn't use them and consider documenting this information in the documentation of the function and not in type hints.

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning type hinting by myself and I have some trouble understanding `TypeVar` and, in this case, `ParamSpec` as to why they take a string argument. Moreover, in all of the examples I could find online, the string is the same as the variable name (in this case, `'P'` and `P`). Why is there such an argument in the first place, and why should those two be the same?

Comment: The string argument is effectively ignored, only used for debugging and error messages, I think. Making them the same avoids confusion over what the error message is referring to. (Whatever raises the error doesn't necessarily have access to the *name* the `TypeVar` instance is bound to, only the instance itself.)

Comment: @habrewning General lack of type hints make things more complicated, not the other way round, and severely limit the power of static analysis tools. There's a reason why many major dynamic languages are working heavily on their type hinting. Also, the massive popularity of Python is largely driven by non-software engineers, and, as a software engineer, I'm not interested to follow their way of writing code.

Comment: @async Do you have an example what is more complicated when no type hints are used? What is the benefit of static analysis tools for dynamic languages? Do you think that all the features that are impossible with static typing are neglectable?

Comment: Consider `def foo(x, y): return x - y`. With dynamic typing, you won't find out that `foo("x", "y")` is an error until you actually try to call the function. If you hint it with `def foo(x: int, y: int): return x - y`, then a static type checker can flag it as an error much more efficiently than actually running your code.

Comment: @chepner But the simplest test case would reveal this. We cannot expect that static types make testing obsolete. Never trust a line of code, that you have not tested at least once. In this case you don't even have to spend much effort to find this stupid error. And another question: Why shouldn't it be possible to call `foo` with float numbers or with complex numbers? Isn't your type hint actually an unnecessary restriction?

Comment: I didn't say they make testing obsolete. But static type checking is faster (and safer) than having to execute your code, so the more errors you can catch *without* having to execute your code, the better.

Comment: `from numbers import Number; def foo(x: Number, y: Number): return x - y`.

Comment: If you need to, imagine that type annotations allow Python to *generate* the "simplest tests" without you having to write them explicitly.

Comment: Yes, it's worth the effort. Restricting your code is the *point*: you don't allow values to be passed to a function that won't ultimately work.

Comment: Why would you then use a language with dynamic typing, type hints with no effect and all sorts of dynamic programming features? What about closures or multiple dynamic dispatch? Do you want to define classes for everything? What if I don't want OO programming? How can I achieve then polymorphism? Do I have to write my own template mechanism like the one in C++? How can I template something, if there is no compilation? Why should I make things static if there is no compilation? Have you ever done Unit Testing if you cannot quickly stub a class? I don't think, what you want is worth the effort.

Comment: Static Typing is helpful in areas, where safety, certification, reliability, discipline or refactoring techniques are a topic. But there are situations where you want a dynamic system, where nothing is known in advance. For example a parser generator. Grammar parsing is always a similar thing. But the types of data that the parser generates, are not known by the parser. See the consequences: In C you need preprocessors like flex/bison. If you want to develop a GUI in Qt, you need the moc preprocessor. That is the consequence of static typing. In Python all this is much easier.